# If $\alpha = 2$cos$(2\pi/5)$ satisfies the equation $x^2+x-1 = 0$ then conclude that the regular $5$-gon is constructible by straightedge and compass.

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry, field-theory

Use the fact that $\alpha = 2\cos(\frac{2\pi}{5})$ satisfies the equation $x^2+x-1 = 0$ to conclude that the regular $5$-gon is constructible by straightedge and compass.

Attempt: $\alpha = 2\cos(\frac{2\pi}{5})$ satisfies the equation $x^2+x-1 = 0$. Recall by theorem that if $\beta$ is construtible, then so is $\sqrt{|\beta|}$.

We know $x^2+x-1 = 0$.  is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, and that for any root $\alpha $ of $p(x)$, $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha): \mathbb{Q}] = 2$. Also, if $\frac{2\pi}{5}$ is a constructible angle so is $2\cos(\frac{2\pi}{5})$.

And recall $\sin^2\theta = 1 - \cos^2\theta$, thus $\sin(\frac{2\pi}{5}) = \sqrt{(1 - \cos^2(\frac{2\pi}{5})}$ is also constructible.

Can someone please help me? I don't know how to continue. Do they assume I have to do a pentagon using a straightedge and compass?

Comment: Where are you confused?  Have you successfully shown that $2cos(\frac {2\pi}{5})$ is a root of that quadratic?  If so, then you know that $\frac {2\pi}{5}$ is a constructible angle, but the interior angle of the regular pentagon is just $\frac {3\pi}{5}$ so that angle is constructible as well (it's just $\pi$ minus the angle you are working with). That's really all you need.

Comment: So the regular 5 gon is constructible if and only if $2\pi/5$ is consttructible . Then  the angle of each vertex of a regular 5 gon is equal to the suplement $3\pi/5$

Comment: Yes, that's it exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with 2 points in the plane separated by a distance $1$, and if $A$ and $B$ are constructible lengths then so are  $\sqrt A,A+B,|A-B|,AB,$ and (if $ B\ne 0$ ) so is $A/B$, by some fairly simple geometric constructions. And every positive integer is a constructible length. Using all this and the quadratic formula,if $A,B,C$ are constructible lengths with $A\ne 0$, and the real number $x$ satisfies $ Ax^2+B +C=0$ then $x$ is constructible. Hence $D=\alpha /2=\cos (2\pi /5)$ is. So take points $p,q$ a distance  $D$ apart.Draw circle  $\Sigma$ centered at $p$, with radius $1$, draw line $l$ thru $q$ , perpendicular to the line thru $p,q$. Then $\Sigma$ meets the line thru $p,q$ at a point $r$  with $q$ between $p$ and $r$ , and $\Sigma$ meets $l$ at points $s_1$ and $s_2$ . The triangle $p ,r, s_1$ is one fifth of a regular pentagon centered at $p$.